# Is this a safe way to store credit cards?

Tags: credit-card, pci-compliance

Basically I'm working on a site where it will process credit cards.
But when a transaction/charge is placed I would like to store information about the credit card in a database.

Right now, I've been thinking of storing the first 4 and last 4 numbers and the expiry date.
But I wont store it in plan text, I've created my own encryption method.

Is that safe enough?

Comment: Why not use something like stripe, taking the pci-compliance out.

Comment: How good is your encryption method?

Comment: The best thing to do is just one round of MD5 followed by a 2ROT13. If you want to be even more secure, you can use _2_ MD5 + 4ROT13.

Comment: @paddy, the answer to "how good is your encryption method?" is almost invariably "nowhere near good enough" :-)

Comment: I might not be aware enough to know if you're serious, or trolling, @Cole. Regardless, I encourage you to delete your comment.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, you need to be more aware, and Cole needs to learn how to use smileys :-) Any suggestion of 2ROT13 is obviously humour.

Comment: You have more faith in our fellow devs, and future readers, than I do, @pax.

Comment: @Jonnny I'm in Australia. Stripe isn't available for me.

Comment: @paddy my encryption is a custom function that uses multiply encryption methods in it. Credit Card numbers would be passed through my custom function at least 5 times.

Comment: I'd like to add that the first 4 and last for would be stored in different columns in json format (eg: `{"salt":"numbers"}`).

Also, theirs still 8 numbers of the credit card and cvv, not being entered into our database at all. Witch should make it more secure?

Comment: please tell us your site; we'll avoid using it.

Comment: @ChrisMaher Using multiple encryption schemes leads to weaker encryption.

Comment: @paddy how so? I thought that since it's using more encryption methods it's stronger, less change of them decoding it since they can't use a pre made list like http://www.md5decrypter.co.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a PCI Compliancy perspective, storing only the first four, last four in plain text is fine. PCI actually allows plain text storage of the first six digits (this is known as the IIN or Issuer Identifier Range), and last four digits (the very last digit is a checksum).

These are similar to the standards for printed receipts, which allow the first six and last three digits to be printed.

Your question does understandably ring alarm bells though. If you (or your systems) have access to the full card number, then you are in the scope of PCI-DSS. Monitoring and maintaining compliance can be time consuming and costly, especially where your compliance must be verified by a third party QSA (Qualified Security Assessor).

The better approach then would be to use a payment gateway that is already PCI compliant. They would be able to perform the card authorization/settlement and return to you a token id and/or a hash of the card number which is safe to store in your database.

Answer (score 4):

Is it safe enough? Let me think. Hmm, I'd like you to consider the rather large number of data breaches that have occurred over the last few years, from sites that people assumed would be safe.

Sites like Sony, the NHS, EverNote, Yahoo, Ubisoft, Apple, Blizzard and even the NSA (who you would *think* would be best at protecting its own information). From [here](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2013/07/the-worlds-biggest-data-breaches-visualised/):

[image]

In addition, it's unlikely your homegrown encryption would stand up to determined attacks.

But the real question is: why do you *need* the information? The information really belongs to the owner of the card and any site that stores it is reducing that owner's safety. It may be better to use a different identifier for the customer and store a non-reversible hash value for the card number if you need to know something like how many different cards they use. While a hash would get collisions across the entire search space of card numbers, the chance of collisions within a single customer is much much smaller.

You may also find that legislation limits what you can store, depending on your jurisdiction.

Comment: [Your own computer?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/_NSAKEY)

Comment: But don't these sites/companies store fill credit card numbers?, not just parts of the credit card numbers?

Comment: @Chris, they may well store them, I have no idea. What I'm saying is that they almost certainly _shouldn't_ store them. There's certain info you may want to keep for audit purposes but someone's ccn shouldn't be part of that, especially after the txn is done. Once you have the money from the bank, there is zero reason to maintain the ccn.